# Why am I getting so many random users on my (currently) private firebase app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

My app is on the google playstore but only in alpha so far, otherwise there is no external access to the app. However, as the question says, I'm seeing a lot of random users with the exact same email pattern `$FIRSTNAME$LASTNAME.$RANDINT@gmail.com`.

[image]

Is this as part of Google's vetting process or what has happened?

Comment: If you suspect bad behavior, contact Firebase support directly for assistance. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson I have done this and will report back. I didn't know if this was a normal problem or not. In the mean time I have generated a new `google-services.json` file

Comment: I've seen this come up at least 3 other times.  It could be abusive behavior, but you will have to work that out with support.

Comment: What's odd though is that I haven't even released the app to anyone outside of friends & family yet.

Comment: I understand - the other three are the same way.  Please explain that to support.  There is nothing that Stack Overflow can do about this.

Comment: We are also experiencing this, have you found reason?

Comment: Happening to us too. I highly doubt a keys leak. Anyone find a solution?

Comment: Any update on why this occurs?

Comment: Same issue here: also an app that is only in testflight and internal testing. I can also see that the random users haven't logged in correctly via the app, so these aren't users from alpha release or testflight. The only random user I can identify is ...cloudtestlabaccounts,com: this address is used by prelaunch report in Google Play and this one logged in correctly via the app.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to Google automatically testing your app (possibly via [Pre-Launch Report](https://play.google.com/console/about/pre-launchreports/)).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64383080/1759443) suggestions it's beneficial.

> It will sign in users as part of its automated testing. This automated testing is generally a good thing for your app.

[Here is an anecdote from a Redidtor](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/16bm6z3/comment/jzekyoc/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

> Google testing your app with bot accounts when you upload a new version of your app. From my experience it usually limited to first day and not more than 20 accounts.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63914762/1759443) mentions you can change the behavior (e.g. specify test account to use in auth).