# How to prevent Firebase spam registrations with Google authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I just released my Firebase based app on Google Play and using Flutter Firebase Auth package https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social

I started noticing lots of spam registrations. How do I know they are spam? They do not create a user table that my app creates in Firebase on app launch, just an entry in the Firebase Authentication list, and their names follow the same pattern:
firstnamelastname1234567@gmail.com
What can be done to prevent these, but preserve the simplicty of Google social authentication?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those accounts are probably being created by the pre-launch report the runs automatically after you publish an app.  It will sign in users as part of its automated testing.  This automated testing is generally a good thing for your app.

There's nothing you can do to prevent these accounts from being created, unless you are able to opt out of the [Play pre-launch report](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en) (which is powered by Firebase Test Lab).  In that link, there is a section that talks about disabling the report.

If you don't disable it, the best you can do is somehow figure out which ones you don't want, then delete them yourself.

Comment: Thanks Doug. Yeah, I just pondered if those are G accounts. Thanks for confirming